# sql server 2000/2008 query optimization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

can you please help me to optimize the following query. Its taking a very long time.

```
delete from dbo.tgrid_detl  
    where F_TRANS_CD = 'R'
    and SOURCE_ID = 'BVT'
    and not exists
        (select rr.BVT_SOURCE_KEY
             from nurdevusrt.VBVT_RNEWL_RTENTN_DETL RR
         where dbo.tgrid_detl.BVT_SOURCE_KEY = rr.BVT_SOURCE_KEY
         and  YEAR(RR.X_POLICY_XPRTN_DT)>=2009 
         and rr.F_BVT_DIV_NO not in (37,65,88))
```

**EDIT**

I am using sql server 2008 but I can use the syntax of either sql server 2000 or sql server 2008 to optimize the query. Could you please help with some solution.

Thanks

Comment: You have added a 2008 tag but your title says 2000. Wich one is it?

Comment: Can you post an execution plan?

Comment: Sorry I can't share the execution plan. I don't have permissions for the same. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Immediate thought:

- indexes are poor or not there
- you have triggers
- VBVT_RNEWL_RTENTN_DETL is some horrendous view

Also, change

```
YEAR(RR.X_POLICY_XPRTN_DT)>=2009
```

to

```
 RR.X_POLICY_XPRTN_DT >= '20090101' AND RR.X_POLICY_XPRTN_DT < '20100101'
```

You index column `x`, not `f(x)` where f is a function

Comment: sorry I didn't get the meaning of x and f(x). which colum I should index.

Comment: +1 for additional possible performance problems and the function comment.

Comment: @user863952 - SQL Server can't use an index when you use a function on a column *(YEAR(RR.X_POLICY_XPRTN_DT))* but by rewriting the statement like gbn does, sit *can* use an index on that column.

Comment: thanks a lot. m query is working fine with making all these changes. thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try following equivalent statement but most likely either

- you don't have sufficient indexes or
- your tables are *really* big or
- your server can't keep up

#### Delete script

```
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM dbo.tgrid_detl
FROM    dbo.tgrid_detl
        LEFT OUTER JOIN nurdevusrt.VBVT_RNEWL_RTENTN_DETL RR
          ON dbo.tgrid_detl.BVT_SOURCE_KEY = rr.BVT_SOURCE_KEY 
             and YEAR(RR.X_POLICY_XPRTN_DT) >= 2009 
             and rr.F_BVT_DIV_NO not in (37,65,88)
WHERE   rr.BVT_SOURCE_KEY IS NULL
        and F_TRANS_CD = 'R' 
        and SOURCE_ID = 'BVT' 

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Thanks for immediate reponse. This query is compartively better than one which I posted. I have huge tables, could you please suggest me some index on the these tables which can help to improve the query performance.

Comment: Whether LEFT JOIN or EXISTS doesn't matter: EXISTS is usually better because it is a semi-join

Comment: @user863952 - My first attempt would be to create a covering index on BVT_SOURCE_KEY, F_TRANS_CD and SOURCE_ID.

Comment: ... and on BVT_SOURCE_KEY, X_POLICY_XPRTN_DT and F_BVT_DIV_NO

Comment: thanks a lot. m query is working fine with making all these changes. thanks once again.